# Ansible: get docker container output during container creation

Tags: ansible, sentry, docker-container

I'm trying to create a docker container which generates a secretkey using Ansible, but the docker_container doesn't seem to return the container output.

If I ssh into the server and run

```
root@localhost:~# docker run --rm sentry-onpremise config generate-secret-key
```

I get the desired output. A secret key such as this

```
q16w8(5s9_+%4@z8m%c%0uzb&agf0pn+6zfocraponasww&r)f
```

But if I try to run the same command using an Ansible playbook, the docker container is executed, but no value is returned:

```
...
- name: Cria secret key para utilizacao em passos seguintes
  docker_container:
    name: sentry-key-generator
    cleanup: True
    image: sentry-onpremise
    command: config generate-secret-key
  register: saida
  tags:
    - debug

- fail:
    msg: "Valor de saida: {{ saida }}"
  tags:
    - debug
...
```

> fatal: [45.56.93.133]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false, 
>       "failed": true, 
>       "invocation": {
>           "module_args": {
>               "msg": "Valor de saida: {u'changed': True, u'ansible_facts': {}}"
>           }, 
>           "module_name": "fail"
>       }, 
>       "msg": "Valor de saida: {u'changed': True, u'ansible_facts': {}}" }

Is this a limitation with the docker_container module? Do I have to setup any other configuration in docker or ansible to get the container output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was introduced in Ansible 2.2.x, that strips `ansible_docker_container` away from results.

See:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22323
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20543

Patch:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/22324/files

The fix is to be released with Ansible 2.3.x

Comment: I'll test the development/2.3 branch tomorrow to check if the issue was fixed. Thanks!

Comment: My ubuntu updated Ansible to version 2.3, but still didn't fix the issue. I'm getting a lot of data about the container (volumes, networks, names, etc), but not the data the containers spits out to stdout visible by the host. Any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you set `detach: false` ?

Comment: I did not. Indeed I missed that detail! Thanks